# Binding и отмена изменений

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Есть класс. Например такой

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

Ну, это ВМ и реализует интерфейс изменения свойств

Есть разметка xaml, например такая

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Prop1}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Prop2}"/>
<Button Content="Сохранить"/>
<Button Content="Отменить"/>
```

То есть есть форма для редактирования экземпляра класса MyClass, в которую мы передаем в качестве параметра конструктора (или иным способом) экземпляр. Теперь вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы работали кнопочки Сохранить и Отменить? Редактирование текстовых полей в примере приводит к изменению свойств класса в реальном времени. Когда то я использовал для этого `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit`, но по ряду причин мне это не нравится. Еще есть идея продублировать экземпляр (то есть в форму отправить его копию), но мне такой вариант в конкретном случае вообще не подходит. Какие еще есть варианты?

**UPD:**

Я попробую объяснить, почему предложенные мною же выше решения меня не устраивают. Мне нужно решение, которое будет очевидным для человека, который в дальнейшем может принять участие в расширении функционала. А первое, что бросится в глаза будет передача экземпляра класса форме, свойства класса и их соответствие полям в разметке xaml. И если в очевидное внести изменения, не внеся их в неочевидное (в функцию копирования класса, например), то это в лучшем случае приведет к ошибке, к которую легко будет отследить, хоть и на это потребуется время. В худшем случае это приведет к ошибочным данным, которые всплывут спустя неопределенное время.

Comment: А чем вас дубль не устраивает? Вполне вариант на мой взгляд, если нельзя менять основной класс.

Comment: @Monk, тем, что для дублирования класса нужно либо описывать копирование всех свойств (и не забывать добавлять новые свойства в функцию копирования, а новые свойства в класс может добавить и другой человек), либо нужно делать через рефлекшн, что может повлечь за собой непредвиденные ситуации, когда/если другой человек будет расширять класс.

Comment: MyClass - класс модели или вьюмодели? Если модели, то отложенное изменение с отменой как раз реализует вьюмодель и это легко. А если вьюмодели, то изменение в рантайме не выглядит проблемой, что сохранение что отмена завершает работу с вм.

Comment: @Monk, вьюха. Дело в том, что свойства вьюхи берут значения из свойств модели. И туда же сохраняют

Comment: Вьюха настроек в вашем случае должна это делать только при нажатии сохранить, а не на каждом вызове сеттера у свойства.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать решить следующим образом.

1) Создать свой атрибут, которым будут помечаться свойства, могут меняться в диалоге.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class RememberAttribute {}
```

2) Пометить этим атрибутом свойства, которые нужно запомнить:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [Remember]
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

3) Создать класс, который будет запоминать значения всех свойств модели представления, помеченных этим атрибутом. Тут, вероятно, придется повозиться с коллекциями, вложенными свойствами и т.д (если необходимо).

```
public class StateSaver<T> where T : ViewModel 
{
    // здесь восстанавливаем исходное состояние модели представления
    public void Restore() { ... } 
}
```

4) Перед показом диалога сохранять состояние класса, а затем, если нужно, откатывать изменения

```
class SomeVm
{
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

    void ShowMyClass()
    {
        var stateSaver = new StateSaver(myClass);

        // здесь все зависит от того, каким образом у вас организован метод для показа модели представления в новом окне
        // можно, например, сделать так, чтобы он принимал stateSaver и самостоятельно вызывал метод Restore
        ShowInDialog(myClass, stateSaver); 
        // либо он может возвращает какой-нибудь dialogResult, на основе которого будут отменены изменения
    }
}
```

А к вашему варианту можно прикрутить AutoMapper. Тогда не нужно будет следить за изменением перечня свойств в модели представления.

Comment: что за класс `ViewModel `?

Comment: Какая-то базовая модель представления. Вы же планируете показывать в новом окне модели представления. Поэтому имеет смысл ограничить функциональность для работы с ними.

Comment: Ясно. Было бы понятнее, если бы вы назвали "Какую-то базовую модель представления" не `ViewModel` а `SomeViewModel` :) А способ я покручу, поверчу и отпишу